# Бот в telegram не отвечает на команды на python

Tags: python-telegram-bot

в консоли код ошибок не даёт, но в приложении telegram нет ответа на команды
P.s.:В похожих сообщениях ответа не нашёл.

```
import telebot;
from telebot import types

token = "Не буду палить"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token);

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    if message.text == "Хай":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")

    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши Хай")

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")


    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо ```from_user``` написать ```chat```. Лично у меня так в боте написано, и все работает

Answer (score 0):

Поставь bot.polling() в начало строки без отступов. У меня всё заработало.